# Loading large variables in succession in Python

Tags: python, performance, memory, ram, hdf5

> System configuration: Ubunut 14.04, RAM: 128 GB, Intel Xeon E5-2630 v3 @ 2.40GHz × 16, ~ 5 GB / 128 GB is occupied before each run.

I have two HDF5 files, each of size 22.5 GB. The python code template is of the form:

```
for i in range(10)
    h5f  = h5py.File(<FILE_PATH_1>,'r')
    data1 = h5f[<VARIABLE_NAME>][:] #22.5 GB size
    h5f  = h5py.File(<FILE_PATH_2>,'r')
    data2 = h5f[<VARIABLE_NAME>][:] #22.5 GB size

    # Do some processing

    del data1
    del data2
```

Now, loading `data1` takes ~ 10 seconds. The RAM goes upto ~ 25 GB. When the second variable starts loading, it quickly fills up memory till ~ 32 GB (as quick as `data1` filled it up), then it becomes extremely slow (about 0.2 GB per second). So loading `data2` takes ~ 100 seconds. If I load another file, it is equally slow.

Basically, any loading after 32 GB of RAM gets filled up is slow. Is there any way to solve this problem? If this requires writing HDF files in a different way, I am open to that too (obvious way being, keep each file < 16 GB so that two files don't fill up RAM till 32 GB).

Comment: That might be a problem with your system or computer...

Comment: Ok. We have two identical computers with the same configuration. I can check on other system and post the numbers here later.

Comment: How are you loading the data?  Ideally, you wouldn't have to read the entire file into memory at once and could just process it in chunks.

Comment: @BrendanAbel I added some details about how I am loading. Loading in chunks sounds a good idea, I can choose chunks such that those don't go upto 32 GB. That works as far as I just tested. However, I am interested in this 32 GB barrier. As mentioned before, it may be a problem with the machine, which I will look into a little later.

Comment: You have 128Gb of RAM, but you do not mention how many of that amount is FREE. As systems very like to consume available ram for cache, or so, it can be case, that you do not have a lot of free ram immediately available and your systems must made movements before it will be able to allocate it for your second file.

Comment: @ZadaZorg Approximately 5 GB is occupied before each run.

Comment: Maybe some caching is involved, either in RAM or in your disk? Are the times like that after a computer restart as well? (If you can test that). What disk(s) do you have?

Comment: You might try examining the `swappiness` value in the kernel: see [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#What_is_swappiness_and_how_do_I_change_it.3F) for some simple commands.

Comment: What happens if you disable swap-space - swapoff -a -v  (man swapoff)